# Get shortcode content via ajax failed on wordpress 4.9.8

Tags: ajax, wordpress

For a custom needs, i should load content of some posts via ajax into a custom template page.
i used **apply_filters( 'the_content', $key->content );** and it was working perfect on my wordpress pages. But when i have update the version of WP to 4.9.8 
it has stopped and ajax response is just an empty string for some shortcodes or a non completely loaded content for some others.

after some search i add this snippet

/* --- Necessary since Visual Compoer V 4.9 --- */
    if ( class_exists( 'WPBMap' )
 && method_exists( 'WPBMap',
 'addAllMappedShortcodes' ) ) {

```
WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

}
else{
do_action( 'template_redirect' ); 


}
```

but the problem was not solved!

My code is:

jQuery.ajax({
                    url: postdigital.ajax_url,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        action: 'get_activContent_byID_posts',
                        post_id: idContent
                    },
                    success: function (response) {

```
            //  console.log(response+' tesssst');  

                }  
            });
```

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_activContent_byID_posts', 'get_activContent_byID_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_activContent_byID_posts', 'get_activContent_byID_posts' ); 
function get_activContent_byID_posts(){
    global $wpdb;

```
$divContent=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT type, content FROM  `tablename` WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['post_id']);
/* --- Necessary since Visual Compoer V 4.9 --- */
if ( class_exists( 'WPBMap' ) && method_exists( 'WPBMap', 'addAllMappedShortcodes' ) ) {
WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

}
else{
do_action( 'template_redirect' ); 


}


foreach($divContent as $key) 
{


      $html= apply_filters( 'the_content', $key->content );  




}

echo $html;     

wp_die(); // wp_die() instead of die() provides better integration with WordPress
```

}

Comment: can you show the code that worked before update?

Comment: @IvnH i have editing my post and adding the code